# can we use wiremock with ldap service?

Tags: spring-ldap, wiremock, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to search but couldn't find an answer to it. 
I recorded a few http calls for mocking external services but not sure if I can record and use ldap call with wiremock. I am using spring ldap template to connect to ldap (org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate).

Comment: you might try ApacheDS, UnboundID.UnboundID has more documentations and examples than ApacheDS.